# How to show that $\overline{zw}=\overline{z}\,\overline{w}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I thought about first multiplying two complex which aren't in the conjugate form:

$$zw=a c+i a d+i b c-b d$$

Then multiply two complex conjugates:

$$\overline{z}\,\overline{w}=a c\color{red}{-}i a d\color{red}{-}i b c-b d$$

And then note the differences between them, which are those red signals. Then I thought about expanding $\overline{zw}$ without negating the proper terms:

$$\overline{zw}=\overline{a c+i a d+i b c-b d}$$

And then apply the overline as if it were an operation to negate those two signals:

$$\overline{zw}=a c-i a d-i b c-b d$$

Is my reasoning correct? I'm thinking it is but I'm feeling that something is missing.

Comment: Yep that's fine. Why did you think there might be something missing?

Comment: Isn't it easier to look for complex numbers in the form $\rho e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: @DanielRust I posted my doubt in amWhy's answer.

Comment: @Artem Sorry, I'm still a noob.

Comment: The next step show that $\overline{\left(\frac{z}{w}\right)} = \frac{\bar z}{\bar w}$

Comment: @nikita2 I'll try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a fine way to proceed. You could make it more explicit by combining like factors, so you have the standard $x + yi$ form, and then conjugating, as you suggest, but the end result would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm feeling something weird: Multiplying $\overline{z}\,\overline{w}$ gives me a guarantee that $\overline{z}\,\overline{w}=a c-i a d-i b c-b d$ but I feel I can't extend that guarantee to $\overline{zw}$.

Comment: You can see this works by expanding $(zw)$, conjugating, factoring the conjugation of $zw$, to obtain the conjugation of $(z)(w)$, then showing this is equal to $\overline z \overline w$

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback too +1

Answer (score 7):

Yes. More concisely,

\begin{align*}
\overline{zw} & =\overline{\left(a+ib\right)\left(c+id\right)}\\
 & =\overline{ac+iad+ibc-bd}\\
 & =ac-iad-ibc-bd\\
 & =\left(a-ib\right)\left(c-id\right)\\
 & =\left(\overline{a+ib}\right)\left(\overline{c+id}\right)\\
 & =\overline{z}\overline{w}
\end{align*}